# I am not able to execute shell script through Jsch

Tags: java, linux, shell, jsch

I am trying to execute the below java code to execute a shell script which is stored on remote server. My code is working perfect when I include `echo stat | nc hostname 2181` in shell script. But when I remove the above command my code is stucking as it is showing connected to hostname and not showing nothing. If I try to execute the `echo stat | nc hostname 2181` command directly in the code then it is showing "String index out of range"  Can any one help. Help will be appreciated.

As my host is a zookeeper I am knowing the status by `echo stat` but including that I also want to print bytes_in_per_second by using `echo`. If I include both commands it works but if I remove `echo stat | nc hostname 2181` then it doesn't works.

Below code there is shell script which I wrote on a remote server.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;

import com.jcraft.jsch.Channel;
import com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelExec;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSch;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException;
import com.jcraft.jsch.Session;

public class Conn {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {


    try { 
        final String host = "hostname";
        final String username = "username";
        final String password = "password";
        final int port = 22;
        final String hostKey = "no";


        final String command5 ="sh /home/user/metrics.sh"; //This the command I used


        final String openSession1 = openSession1(host, username,password,port, hostKey, command5);



    }catch (Exception ase) {
        System.out.println("Caught an Exception:");
        System.out.println("Error Message:    " + ase.getMessage());
    }              


}

public static final String HOST_KEY_CHECKING = "StrictHostKeyChecking";
public static final String EXCUTE_CHANNEL = "exec";
```

//  --------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  openSession
//  --------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
 public static String openSession1(String host, String username,String password, int port, String hostKey, String command5) {

    JSch jsch = new JSch();
    Session session = null;
    Channel channel = null;
    StringBuilder log = new StringBuilder();

    String response = null;


    try {
        session = jsch.getSession(username, host, port);
        session.setPassword(password);
        session.setConfig(HOST_KEY_CHECKING, hostKey);
        session.setConfig("PreferredAuthentications", "publickey,keyboard-interactive,password");
        session.connect();
        // check if connect was successful
        if (session.isConnected()) {
            System.out.println("Connected sucessfully to server :" + host);

             try{
            channel = session.openChannel(EXCUTE_CHANNEL);

            ((ChannelExec) channel).setCommand(command5);
            // channel.setInputStream(System.in);
            channel.setInputStream(null);

            ((ChannelExec) channel).setErrStream(System.err);

            InputStream in = channel.getInputStream();

            channel.connect();  
            response = IOUtils.toString(in);

             }
                catch(Exception e){
                    return e.toString();
                }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Connection Failed" + host);
        }
    } catch (JSchException e) {
        System.out.println("Connection Failed" + host + " Error:" + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Connection Failed" + host + " Error:" + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println( "Sent:"+  response.substring((response.indexOf("Sent: ") + ("Sent: ").length()),
            (response.indexOf("Connections: "))));

    System.out.println( "Received:"+  response.substring((response.indexOf("Received: ") + ("Received: ").length()),
            (response.indexOf("Sent: "))));

    System.out.println( "Connections:"+  response.substring((response.indexOf("Connections: ") + ("Connections: ").length()),
            response.indexOf("Outstanding: ")));



    System.out.println( "Response received :"+  response);
    return response;

}
```

}

metrics.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
echo stat | nc hostname 2181
echo bytes_in_per_second
```

Comment: That seems a very complicated way of running `ssh username@hostname /home/user/metrics.sh`

Comment: If your script starts with `#!/bin/bash` why are you calling it with `sh`? Don't mix your shells. Instead, make the script executable and just call it as if it were a program (ie without the initial `sh`)

Comment: welp, that's odd.  You need to tell us which line of your source code the exception points to.  (e.g. `Conn.java:100` - but we can't see line numbers so you'll have to point the line out to us)

Comment: @roaima Hi tried by removing sh even though it's not working.

Comment: @sourcejedi It's not showing line number where the error exists. FYI it is not an syntax error. It is giving error when it is connecting to channel and then trying to execute the shell script on remote host.

Comment: Isn't that only because this code is badly written though?  What happens if you remove the `try` + `catch` in `main()`, can you see line numbers like I described then?

Comment: @sourcejedi hey I changed the description can you please go through the above question once again. I will try by removing try and catch

Comment: hint: it will be one of the lines containing `response.substring`

Comment: When I tried without removing try and catch then I got Connected sucessfully to server :hostname Caught an Exception: Error Message: String index out of range: -6 and when I try by removing try and catch then I got as Connected sucessfully to server :hostname Exception in thread "main

Comment: Seriously?  The Java environment doesn't show a backtrace for exceptions that leak from `main`?  You can instead use `ase.printStackTrace()` in the catch, if that's your problem.

Comment: Second hint: of the three lines which contain `response.substring`, the exception is going to be thrown by the first one.  Also I have great difficulty believing it says -6 and not 6.  Though I'm sure I've seen weirder bugs in various runtimes.

Comment: *Of course* it doesn't work when you remove the line that produces the output you are parsing so recklessly. What did you expect?

Answer (score 0):

> Of course it doesn't work when you remove the line that produces the output you are parsing.

It should be trivial to determine that the exception "String index out of range: -6" is thrown by this line:

==>    `System.out.println( "Sent:"+  response.substring((response.indexOf("Sent: ") + ("Sent: ").length()),
            (response.indexOf("Connections: "))));`

It was only difficult because you caught the exception and chose to print the message only.

If you printed the stacktrace instead, as in the other `catch` blocks are written, the line number would have been included e.g. `Conn.java:1000`.  That's the method you should have used.

Or preferably, run your program with a standard JDK, without the outer try/catch block.  It will print the stacktrace of un-caught exceptions automatically.  You don't even have to learn a debugger or compile with debug options; Java is just that friendly.

The string `"Sent: "` is no longer present in the response, because you removed the command that produces it.  That's what causes the problem.

You should always post the full error message.  You later admitted the full output was

```
Caught an Exception:
Error Message: String index out of range: -6
```

if we had known this, your debugging issue could have been identified more quickly.